# How to load self-written ruby function into Ruby interactive consoles(irb)?

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple ruby function and I want to test if the function works in irb.

For example,if I defined my function in XXX.rb, I want to test that function in irb

```
  irb(main):001:0> Some ways to load XXX.rb
  irb(main):002:0> I could use functions in XXX.rb
```

Can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the interpreter:

```
load('my_file.rb')
```